# Logical error in Mondrian cube

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I am using this cube to retrieve data from my OLTP Database

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Schema name="Test36">
        <Cube name="Test36Cube">
            <Table name="fact_table"/>
            <Dimension name="Year Month Day" foreignKey="id_date">
                    <Hierarchy hasAll="false" primaryKey="id_date">
                        <Table name="transaction_date"/>
                        <Level name="Year" column="year" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears" type="Numeric"/>
                        <Level name="Month" column="month" uniqueMembers="false" ordinalColumn="monthNumber" nameColumn="month" levelType="TimeMonths" type="Numeric"/>
                        <Level name="Day" column="day" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" type="Numeric"/>
                    </Hierarchy>
            </Dimension>
            <Dimension name="Txn type">
                  <Hierarchy hasAll="false">
                      <Level name="txn type" column="tx_type" uniqueMembers="true"/>
                  </Hierarchy>
            </Dimension>
        <Measure name="Amount" column="tx_amount" aggregator="sum" formatString="Standard"/>
    </Cube>
</Schema>
```

When I add the dimension "Txn type", data for "year month day" is not loaded for each month. Data for only some months is retrived. I am not able to understand the reason behind this error. Can anybody help?

Comment: Not sure, but it may be due to the join between the two dimensions : if, for a given "Txn type", there is no data on a specific month, this one is not displayed.

Comment: @bhericher : you are right. How do I overcome this without changing my data in the OLTP database?

Comment: @bhericher : never mind...I resolved the error. Dimension "Txn Type" was taking the default value since I had assigned hasAll="false". I changed the parameter "hasAll" to "true" and it corrected the problem...thanks for the help